# Cobalt runs out of GPU memory on MIPS platform

Tags: mips, cobalt

When some video icon is in focus and animated preview is looping, it starts increasing GPU memory about 1 MB/s until there is no more memory left. Then on gold build platform starts reporting failure on memory allocation and there are black rectangles on the screen, while debug build  aborts on following check:
`[1205/173644:FATAL:framebuffer.cc(45)] Check failed: 0 == glGetError() (0 vs. 1285)`

When I use cmd flag "--disable_image_animations" video icons are static and there is no GPU memory leak. But this flag is not available for gold build.

I have read memory_tuning.md, tried limiting GPU usage on every possible way, but nothing helped.

What could be the reason why cobalt doesn't free GPU memory?

Environment:
Broadcom SoC with 140 MB of GPU heap memory.
release_11 branch.

Comment: Hi Nikola, that certainly shouldn't be happening!  It sounds like an image asset related to the thumbnails is leaking.  We have a few internal devices that don't exhibit this problem, so that makes me wonder if there is some trouble when releasing the GL resources for those assets.  The animated thumbnails will require a thumbnail-sized GL framebuffer to be created, rendered to, and deleted repeatedly (~10 times per second).  Can you check that this line is getting repeatedly called: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/release_11/src/cobalt/renderer/backend/egl/framebuffer.cc#84 ?

Comment: @AndrewTop I have checked, and that destructor is called repeatedly (~8 times per second). So it must be on some other place where the memory is allocated and not released. I will try to test our gles library if it is working correctly (but it is on arm platform). I will continue to debug this problem, but if you have some tips please inform me.